# spring boot and thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need help with spring [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGHUG.jpg)boot and thymeleaf because it doesn't show me the user roles

because it shows me this information and not the roles

this is my database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiSiY.jpg)

my controller

```
@GetMapping("/listar")
public String listar(Model model) {
        
        List<User> listUsers= userService.findAll();        
        
    if(listUsers !=null) {  
    model.addAttribute("titulo", "Lista de usuarios y roles");
    model.addAttribute("listUsers", listUsers);
    return "user/listar";
    }
        
    return "redirect:/escuela/";
        
    }
```

My HTML

```
<tr th:each="user:  ${listUsers}">
    <td th:text="${user.nombre}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.aPaterno}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.aMaterno}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.curp}">]</td>
    <td th:text="${user.puesto}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>                           
    <td th:text="${user.roles}"></td>
</tr>
```

my entity

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
    @NotBlank
    private String nombre;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
    @NotBlank
    private String aPaterno;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
    @NotBlank
    private String aMaterno;

    @Size(min = 18, max = 18)   
    @Column(length = 18, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String curp;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
    @NotBlank
    private String puesto;

    

    @Email
        @Column(length = 45, nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String email;
    
        @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
        @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
        @NotBlank
        private String password;

@Valid
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
```

gettters and setters.....

I don't have much spring boot experience, can someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this because the `${user.roles}` is a list, so what's displayed is this list's (and consequently the `Role`'s) default `toString()` method,

You need to loop in your `user.roles` and print, for example, the role's name like below:

```
<tr th:each="user:  ${listUsers}">
    <td th:text="${user.nombre}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.aPaterno}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.aMaterno}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.curp}">]</td>
    <td th:text="${user.puesto}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>  
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr th:each="role: ${user.roles}">
                 <td th:text="${role.name}"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>                         
</tr>
```

For the sake of complicity you could also override the `toString()` method in your `Role` class and let your HTML as is, i.e.

```
<td th:text="${user.roles}"></td>
```

Since you haven't posted Role class below is a "guess" of what it might be and the `toString()` method is overridden to display the `name` field.

**Role** class

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    private String name;
    // rest of properties

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: pleft, Excellent, it helped me a lot to understand, thanks